# Preprocessor macro C/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, macros

Hello I am trying to Make A Macro that gets a parameter and tries to add postFix to it.

```
#define myPostFix HelloWorld
#define macro(x) x ##myPostFix 
#define CAlgThreadHandleObject macro(CAlgThreadHandleObject)
```

Expected behavior is to get

```
CAlgThreadHandleObjectHelloWorld
```

What I actually get is:

```
CAlgThreadHandleObjectmyPostFix
```

Can Some1 help me to get the expected behavior please? 
Please note that myPostFix is something I have to define in project GCC definitions and it should vary from project to project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#define myPostFix HelloWorld
#define macro_2(x, y) x##y
#define macro_1(x, y) macro_2(x, y)
#define macro(x) macro_1(x, myPostFix)
#define CAlgThreadHandleObject macro(CAlgThreadHandleObject)
```

You need the intermediate `macro_1` to let the preprocessor substitute `myPostFix` assignement, then `macro_2` to concatenate strings.
This solution let you assign `myPostFix` to the value you want.

To clarify how preprocessor and symbol replacement works consider that the preprocessing translation phase is not recursive on parameters, so the translation need to pass through a **forced** parameter expansion more than one time up to expand all parameters.
In  our case:

1. `CAlgThreadHandleObject` expands to : macro(CAlgThreadHandleObject)
2. `macro(CAlgThreadHandleObject)` expands to : `macro_1(CAlgThreadHandleObject, myPostFix)`
3. `macro_1` expands to: `macro_2(CAlgThreadHandleObject, HelloWorld)`
4. And last `macro_2` expands to: `CAlgThreadHandleObjectHelloWorld`

Comment: Note that the name `_macro` is reserved by the compiler, since it starts with an underscore, you should avoid it if possible.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes you're right. Under strict Ansi words beginning with underscore are reserved for for compiler extensions. I'll fix it. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for clarification on preprocessing expansions.

Answer (score 1):

You actually need to go three layers deep with this one in order to get the macro to expand properly.  I can't pretend to understand the exact reasoning why this is necessary (not that I want to understand...)

```
#define MY_ADDPOSTFIX3(x, y) x ## y
#define MY_ADDPOSTFIX2(x, y) MY_ADDPOSTFIX3(x, y)
#define MY_ADDPOSTFIX(x) MY_ADDPOSTFIX2(x, MY_POSTFIX)

MY_ADDPOSTFIX(Func)
```

You can test this:

```
$ gcc -E test.c -DMY_POSTFIX=HelloWorld
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"




FuncHelloWorld
```

And...

```
$ gcc -E test.c -DMY_POSTFIX=Goodbye | tail -n 1
FuncGoodbye
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it worked :) However I would like to know the reason why so :)

Comment: @user3351949: That would be an excellent question on its own.  I, however, do not share your sentiment.  I already know too much about the C preprocessor and wish I knew less.

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass it through another call of the macro `macro` so the define is expanded. I slightly changed the macros, but the functionality is the same:

```
#define myPostFix HelloWorld
#define macro2(x,y) x##y
#define macro(x,y) macro2(x,y)
#define CAlgThreadHandleObject macro(CAlgThreadHandleObject,myPostFix)
```

Comment: Thank you sir it worked like a charm! 
Could you explain the reason that I have to pass it twice?